# domain access: Alias of a main domain to point to subdomain

Tags: domain-access, subsites

I´ve got an domain-access installation with the default domain "capital.com" and a subdomain "country.capital.com".

I´m struggling now with pointing from a main domain to this subdomain.
Like so:

country.com/travel should lead to country.capital.com/travel but keeps country.com as domain name: country.com/travel

I can´t get it to work with "keeping domain name".
Simple redirect works to load the subdomain, but displays sub.domain.com/.
I can set an alias to point to default domain, which keeps the alias.
How can I point from ALIAS to the SUBDOMAIN?

Any suggestion welcome!

I thought that´s a main feature of domain-access module.
I´m in trouble now - havn´t been aware of this complication!

regards
Vincent

Comment: TLD doesn't mean the main domain. TLDs are .com, .net, .org, .de etc.

Comment: [solved]

I had to set the alias additionally in the drupal-installation:

admin/structure/domain/view/mysubdomain/edit > Alias: *.country.com - no redirect

That simple (at the end):

Sever: Alias-domain: country.com - Parent domain: myDefaultDomain.com - no redirect
+
Drupal: Alias (see above)

Never give up!

Vincent